# Change inline SVG stroke & fill colours depending on the theme

Tags: css, svg, themes, inline, reveal.js

I am trying to adapt the colours (stroke & fill) of an inline SVG picture in Reveal.js depending on the selected theme, i.e., dark strokes and fills for light themes and light stroke and fills for dark themes.
So far I have attempted several approaches defining the following styles for the tags on the themes (in black.css for instance):

```
svg{stroke:white;fill:white}
```

or

```
rect{stroke:white;fill:white}
```

or

```
.reveal. slides rect{stroke:white;fill:white}
```

even defining a class

```
.light{stroke:white;fill:white}
```

but none worked.

Comment: If I define those styles in reveal.css or in a custom additional style file I created and load in the head section (<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">), it works. But of course the colours do not change when changing the theme.

Comment: Can you share your markup for this please.

Comment: Do you use D3 or jQuery in your project?

Comment: I only add, e.g., <svg><rect width="300" height="100" /></svg> in the html file and rect{stroke-width: 4;stroke: lightgray;fill: white;} in the css file. And no, I am not using D3 nor jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close.
Thanks to my favourite method (trial and error), I found a solution. I had to also wrap it with "section", i.e.:

```
.reveal .slides section rect{stroke:white;fill:white}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change DOM elements in runtime:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".light").forEach(el => 
 el.setAttribute('stroke', 'white')
);
```

Comment: I suppose that implies JS. I would prefer sticking to CSS. I successfully am able to change the colour of the logo depending on the theme. I introduced .logo {background-image: url(../../img/white.png);}​ in the black.css theme and .logo {background-image: url(../../img/black.png);}​ in the white.css theme. Why does it not work for svg?

Comment: I tried typing it in reveal.js and in my html file, but I can not make it work. It may also be, that I am not doing it correctly, which is very likely.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it can happen because some browsers don't recognize `fill` and `stroke` as styles, only as attributes...

Comment: Maybe you are right, because they are not highlighted in the editor as the rest, e.g. "background-image". BTW I use Firefox.

Comment: However, it is possible to change svg colours through CSS as proved in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak56tmu1/).

Comment: Did you try it in Chrome?